# Error installing Python 2 via Homebrew on MacOS Mojave

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, homebrew, macos-mojave

I'm having a lot of trouble with installing Python 2.7 on the MacOS 10.14 Mojave Beta.

Yes, I know that Python 2 comes pre-installed on the Mac, but I need a framework build of Python for my task.

I've tried re-installing the command line tools and then installing Python 2.7 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749530/brew-install-zlib-devel-on-mac-os-x-mavericks) and [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/29176#issuecomment-398656987), but am still having issues - below is my output:

```
NickLaptop:~ nicholasarner$ brew reinstall python@2
==> Reinstalling python@2 
==> Downloading https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/Python-2.7.15.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/nicholasarner/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python@2-2.7.15.tar.xz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1 --enable-ipv6 --datarootdir=/usr/l
==> make
==> make install PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1
==> make frameworkinstallextras PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/share/python@
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/04/d6f1159feaccdfc508517dba1929eb93a
Already downloaded: /Users/nicholasarner/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python@2--setuptools-39.2.0.zip
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/e8/2340d46ecadb1692a1e455f13f75e596d
Already downloaded: /Users/nicholasarner/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python@2--pip-10.0.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2a/fb/aefe5d5dbc3f4fe1e815bcdb05cbaab19
Already downloaded: /Users/nicholasarner/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python@2--wheel-0.31.1.tar.gz
==> make html
Last 15 lines from /Users/nicholasarner/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python@2/05.make:
    return build_main(argv)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.5_1/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 22, in build_main
    from sphinx import cmdline
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.5_1/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/cmdline.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sphinx.application import Sphinx
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.5_1/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 29, in <module>
    from sphinx.config import Config
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.5_1/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/config.py", line 21, in <module>
    from sphinx.util import logging
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.5_1/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/util/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from sphinx.util import logging
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.5_1/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/util/logging.py", line 106, in <module>
    class SphinxLoggerAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LoggerAdapter'
make: *** [build] Error 1
Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!
These open issues may also help:
python 3.7.0 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/29490
python upgrade failing https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/29214
app-engine-python 1.9.70 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/28858
molecule: Use correct `docker` python package dependency https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/28635
[root] formula does not link against python@2 correctly. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/29377
clingo add support for lua, use python 3 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/28057
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted for python@2 –with-tcl-tk https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/28168
Error: You are using macOS 10.14.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
Error: You are using macOS 10.14.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT** Please don't suggest Anaconda! For what I'm working on, I specifically need a framework built version of Python via Brew.

**EDIT 2** - I tried reinstalling Sphinx, which happened with no problems. Upon doing that, I tried running `install python@2` again, but had the same issue as before.

Below is the output of running `brew doctor`

```
NickLaptop:~ nicholasarner$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
  /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin/libusb-config

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libFLAC.8.2.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libcdt.5.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libcgraph.6.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libcsnd6.6.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libfltk.1.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libfltk.1.3.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libfltk_forms.1.3.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libfltk_images.1.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libfltk_images.1.3.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libfluidsynth.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgraph.5.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgvc.6.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgvpr.2.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/liblo.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.2.0.2.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libmpadec.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libpathplan.4.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libpng12.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/librealsense.1.12.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libsfml-audio.2.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.2.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libsfml-network.2.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libsfml-system.2.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.2.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libsndfile.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libwiiuse.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libxdot.4.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/arith.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/cdt.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/cgraph.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/color.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/geom.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/graph.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/graphviz_version.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/gvc.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/gvcext.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/gvcjob.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/gvcommon.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/gvconfig.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/gvplugin.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/gvplugin_device.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/gvplugin_layout.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/gvplugin_loadimage.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/gvplugin_render.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/gvplugin_textlayout.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/gvpr.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/pack.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/pathgeom.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/pathplan.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/textpara.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/types.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/usershape.h
  /usr/local/include/graphviz/xdot.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/control.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/intclient.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/jack.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/jslist.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/metadata.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/midiport.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/net.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/ringbuffer.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/session.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/statistics.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/systemdeps.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/thread.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/transport.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/types.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/uuid.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/weakjack.h
  /usr/local/include/jack/weakmacros.h
  /usr/local/include/librealsense/rs.h
  /usr/local/include/librealsense/rsutil.h
  /usr/local/include/runt.h
  /usr/local/include/sndfile.h
  /usr/local/include/soundpipe.h
  /usr/local/include/sporth.h

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
  /usr/local/lib/liblo.la
  /usr/local/lib/libsndfile.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/jack.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libcdt.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libcgraph.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libgraph.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libgvc.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libgvpr.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpathplan.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libxdot.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/sndfile.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
  /usr/local/lib/liblua.a
  /usr/local/lib/librunt.a
  /usr/local/lib/libsndfile.a
  /usr/local/lib/libsoundpipe.a
  /usr/local/lib/libsporth.a

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  lua
  libsndfile
  ruby

Warning: You are using macOS 10.14.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
  /usr/local/bin/git-remote-keybase
  /usr/local/bin/keybase
  /usr/local/bin/lua
  /usr/local/bin/lua-5.2
  /usr/local/bin/lua5.2
  /usr/local/bin/luac
  /usr/local/bin/luac-5.2
  /usr/local/bin/luac5.2
  /usr/local/bin/luarocks
  /usr/local/bin/luarocks-5.2
  /usr/local/bin/luarocks-admin
  /usr/local/bin/luarocks-admin-5.2
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/_brew_services
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-urw-aliases.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf
  /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf
  /usr/local/include/lauxlib.h
  /usr/local/include/lua.h
  /usr/local/include/lua.hpp
  /usr/local/include/lua5.2
  /usr/local/include/luaconf.h
  /usr/local/include/lualib.h
  /usr/local/opt/qt5

Warning: Some installed formulae are missing dependencies.
You should `brew install` the missing dependencies:
  brew install harfbuzz mono

Run `brew missing` for more details.
```

This is the output when running `brew config`:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.6.9-39-g376f67b
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git
HEAD: 376f67bf2c8893a06bf1e42a2375d58e9d8c2670
Last commit: 2 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 69b99b69ff3a9c686b9d9fb0102927c5dd2f373b
Core tap last commit: 3 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_DEV_CMD_RUN: 1
CPU: quad-core 64-bit skylake
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.3_2/bin/ruby
Clang: 10.0 build 1000
Git: 2.17.1 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 1.8.0_131
macOS: 10.14-x86_64
CLT: 10.0.0.0.1.1529074627
CLT headers: 10.0.0.0.1.1529074627
Xcode: 10.0 => /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11
```

Comment: Python 2 comes preinstalled on MacOS. Please check what is the preinstalled version.

Comment: @igrinis: The biggest problem there is that the 2.7.10 release Apple bundles is *seriously* outdated. That's a release from 2015, they should *at least* include 2.7.15. And Python 2 is hitting the big hard end-of-life stop in 17 months time, Apple is falling behind on moving to Python 3 here.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

I was able to fix it by completely uninstalling and reinstalling Python after following step by step in this answer: [How to fix broken python 2.7.11 after OSx updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303294/how-to-fix-broken-python-2-7-11-after-osx-updates)

After the reinstallation the problem was gone

Answer (score 1):

As I read you output - this is not a problem with python directly it is a problem with sphinx which builds the docs. I would go for the following steps:

1. `brew update && brew upgrade`
2. `brew install sphinx` (maybe this gives a better error message or solves the problem if sphinx is installed before)
3. `brew reinstall python@2`

If this is not working: Did you reinstalled the commandline tools after upgrading to mac os 10.14? (`xcode-select --install`). If not installed/updated before do it and retry.

If this all is not working could you please execute brew doctor and post the output so we can better see whats going on with your homebrew instane?

Maybe it could be a option to make an roll back to a stable version of Mac OS (10.13) ?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the response; I tried what you suggested and still had some issues - I updated my question with the output of `brew doctor`.

Comment: Is the error still the same after installing sphinx? Could you make sure that sphinx is working correctly? Just try to build an doc with stand alone sphinx.

Comment: It should be `brew install sphinx-doc` which does fail.

Answer (score -3):

I'd suggest you used the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos) of python. Anaconda offers both python 2.7 and python 3.6 with easy to use python installers for both versions. The Anaconda page explains how to install and run python on your mac.