# ERROR: Loading command: install (LoadError) cannot load such file -- zlib

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler, zlib

I need for my project ruby version 1.9.3.
It was really difficult to instal this version on my Mac(macOS Catalina 10.15.7) via rbenv (it did not work at all via rvm) But after installation all commands `gem install` (bundler, for example), leads to this error.

> ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
> cannot load such file -- zlib
>
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
> uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand

`brew install zlib` says that it has already been installed.

Ruby version was installed successfully through command

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.0)" rbenv install 1.9.3-p551
```

After that I reinstalled it through this command

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.0)
--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11" rbenv install 1.9.3-p551
```

And reinstall my Xcode from 12 version to 11 and back. Nothing worked. Please help!

Comment: It is very complicated issue as even in Mojave zlib was issue. you should look this and try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749530/brew-install-zlib-devel-on-mac-os-x-mavericks as it is all hit and try, or download zlib and manual install